# Controlling one application in another app on Android

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I am developing an Android app and I've successfully integrated Gmail into it by creating a button that opens the Gmail app within my application. Now, I want to enhance the user experience by adding a Floating Action Button (FAB) to control the Gmail interface.

Specifically, I would like to:
Compose Email: How can I use a FAB to open the compose email screen within the integrated Gmail interface in my app?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.